# Keras: expected dense_1_input to have shape (8,) but got array with shape (5,)

Tags: python, keras, classification

I am getting an error message while trying to execute the below code for binary classification in Keras

"Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (8,) but got array with shape (5,)". I have specified input_dim = 5. Not sure what I am missing. Would really appreciate any help on this!

X_Train dataframe shape = (116020, 5)

Y_Train dataframe shape = (116020, )

My Code:

```
model.add(Dense(12,input_dim = 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam", metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train,Y_train, epochs = 1000, batch_size = 10)
```

Comment: does the error happen in compile or in fit?

Comment: It happens in fit

Comment: do you have any idea where the shape (8,) came from?

Comment: I noticed I had numpy.random.seed(7) in the beginning of the code. I changed it to 5 and the code ran fine! Thanks

Comment: you should ask another question for why the random seed affects the code working or not. im certainly interested